# Generating texture atlas in C# with OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm making a game that uses a lot of textures (about 100 textures), and I know that a call to `glBindTexture` is expensive, so I want to build an atlas of all the textures, but don't know how to approach the problem. Here are the requirements:

- We can create multiple textures for the atlas (pages)
- All textures are rectangular, and assumed to be smaller than 512x512
- We should create as little pages as possible
- Images may not be rotated, just translated
- OpenGL 3.3 is used

What algorithm could be used to generate such an arrangement of all the textures, with a priority on space efficiency over speed.

Comment: please provide more details: are all your textures rectangular? do you do any filtering or mipmapping? what version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: @YakovGalka i've edited my question. i'm using opengl 3.3, don't use filtering, nor mipmapping, and my textures are rectangular and should be only translated (not rotated/scaled)

Comment: There is the [stb_rect_pack](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_rect_pack.h) public domain library which worked great for me before. However it's written in C, so you'll need to make a C# binding for it. If all your textures are one of the few distinct sizes (like your unedited question suggested), you could use a couple of texture arrays -- one for each size. Those are core since OpenGL 3.0.